# List Contains() comparing Doubles in Java / Groovy

Tags: java, groovy

So I have this expression:

`[8.42431001E10].contains(getSomeValue('000000084243100100'))`

the getSomeValue(String value) converts the string to a double.

```
public Object getSomeValue(String value) {
 if (NumberUtils.isNumber(value)) {
      try { 
        result = NumberUtils.createDouble(value);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        result = value;
      }
    } else {
      result = value;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Which means that `getSomeValue('000000084243100100')` returns 8.42431001E10

However the expression above `[8.42431001E10].contains(getSomeValue('000000084243100100'))` returns false even though i expect it to be true.

when converting everything to string such as this one:
`["8.42431001E10"].contains(getSomeValue('000000084243100100').toString())` returns true.

I want to understand how to make it return to true as a double value, not string.

I have also tried doing this:

```
[8.42431001E10].contains(Double.valueOf(getSomeValue('000000084243100100')))
```

But still false.

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: I have discovered that this works: 
``` [Double.valueOf(8.42431001E10)].contains( getSomeValue('000000084243100100'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The "number literal" in Groovy gives you a `BigDecimal` (instead of
float/double like in many other (jvm-)languages).  And `BigDecimal` is
accurate and double/float is not (it's an approximation for the sake of
speed over accuracy).

```
def x = 8.42431001E1
println x.getClass()
// → class java.math.BigDecimal
println(x==Double.valueOf('000000084243100100'))
// → false
```

So you have to cast one side to the same type to make them comparable.

Since both numbers actually don't have fractions this begs the question,
why not to use `BigInteger` in the first place for both sides anyway.